# How to travel to a non bottom bar screen with a single navhost?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a project where their are 4 screens in total. Home, Setting, rewards and connect. The bottom bar will contain 3 screens Home, Connect and Reward. However on the Home screen you can travel to the setting screen. I know you can hide and show a bottom bar as a solution to show a non bottom bar screen. I would like to see if there is a different way. I was thinking of finding a solution where the home screen is a nested graph that contains home and setting screen and adding that to the bottom bar. I would like to know if this a good approach or if they're are any other solutions.